# Search/print specific elements in array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Anyone know how to search (with luck) for specific elements in an array? I'v tried about everything - except the correct way.

My two corresponding char-arrays looks something like this:

```
char array1[10][10]={"Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Alpha2"};   //room for some more here
char array2[10][10]={"123456","234567","345678","456789","567890"};   //room for some more here
```

I can print them all by the regular for-loop:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%s  %s \n", &array1[i], &array2[i]);
}
```

But let's say I want do the same loop, and only print the two elements starting with 'A' (the first and last one). I thought something like this would work

```
do {
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("Name: %s\nDate: %s\n\n", &array1[i][x], &array2[i]);
        }
    } while (x=='A');
```

That's the same for-loop, except I put the extra [x] behind &array1 to tell my 'x' have to match the first character in each element of array1 (like it will only do the for loop while (x=='A') - which is the first letter in the elements I want.

But it doesn't do any good..

Anyone have a better solution? I've tried other variants of the for loop also, without luck. I'm just stuck now...

Comment: Hint: `&array1[i][x]` is not address of _array_.

Comment: Q: by using `while (x=='A');` what do you want to achieve? it seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up, I'm mixing a bit when it comes to adresses, pointers and stuff.. About the (x=='A') my idea was to search for the letter 'A' in the second part of &array1[i][x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char array1[10][10]={"Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Alpha2"};   //room for some more here
char array2[10][10]={"123456","234567","345678","456789","567890"};   //room for some more here
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(array1[i][0]=='A')   //add this statement in your code
    printf("%s  %s \n", &array1[i], &array2[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shan. This worked like a charm. So there was no need for my x then, but instead refer to [0]. You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

using while you are checking `x=='A'` it will compare with the ASCII value of A. The condition is wrong.
 you can use
`while((strncmp(array,"A",1)) == 0)`
this will check the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

> except I put the extra [x] behind &array1 to tell my 'x' have to match the first character in each element of array1

That's not quite how array subscripts work. As you have found, `array1[i]` will refer to the `i`th string in `array1`. You can then access the `x`th character in `array1[i]` by indexing into the string, i.e. `array1[i][x]`.

You don't actually assign `x` anywhere, so you'll end up with undefined behaviour. What you want to do is extract the first character of `array1[i]` (i.e. element zero), so the following is possible:

```
char x = '\0';

do {

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        x = array1[i][0];
        printf("Name: %s\nDate: %s\n\n", &array1[i][x], &array2[i]);
        }
    } while (x=='A');
```

You'll then notice that this probably doesn't give the behaviour you want. It'll loop over all 10 strings, *then* perform the `x == 'A'` check. You should move that inside the loop instead, e.g.

```
char x = '\0';
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    x = array1[i][0];
    if(x == 'A')
       printf("%s  %s \n", &array1[i], &array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. As you mention, your first example give some unwanted behavior. The second part nearly worked.. It gave me the correct values - however I got (NULL)-values on the first array. It might be caused by using wrong addressing (&array[i] and not array[i]) which was mentioned in another comment. But thanks anyway, it lead me in the correct direction.